# Outlook Calendar Integration With iOS App

Tags: ios, outlook

I am trying to integrate outlook calendar with iOS App.

I have integrated the libraries using pods successfully.

**Podfile Contents are given below:**

target 'swift-tutorial' do

pod 'ADALiOS', '~> 1.2'

pod 'Office365', '~> 0.10'

end

target 'swift-tutorialTests' do

end

But while running the app, I am getting the following error:

**../Pods/Office365/sdk/directory_services/Generated/Operations/MSDirectoryDirectoryObjectCollectionFetcher.h:27:63: Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MSOrcCollectionFetcher'**

I also tried to run the sample project in the following URL:

https://github.com/jasonjoh/swift-tutorial

But I am still getting the same issue there too.

Did anyone come across this issue before? Is there any error with the library itself?